# Superposition with Structograms

Tags: diagrams, struktex

I am using `struktex` to design some structograms ([NSD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nassi%E2%80%93Shneiderman_diagram)), and I want to have a file with two of them in a row, and eventually copy and paste either into my larger file.

I wrote the first (here shown only partially), everything was fine.

I wrote the second (here shown only partially) in another file, everything was fine.

I copied and pasted the second into my first file, and the two got superposed.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}    
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{cancel}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{struktex}
\numberwithin{equation}{section}

\begin{document}
This is the structogram for the reactor model, including the deactivation
\begin{center}
\begin{struktogramm}(100,50)[Model with Deactivation]
\assign{Get the values from \tt{global}}
\assign{get the value for the parameter estimation}
\assign{Rename \tt{y} variables to \tt{T},\tt{P},$\rho$ and \tt{a}}
\assign[10]{\bf{First Mesh Point}}
\assign{Calculate $c_{p_1}$ and $Q_{1}$}
\assign{\tt{for i = 1:}$N_c$}
\forever
\assign{Mass Balance on the first mesh point of component \tt{i}}
\foreverend
\assign{Energy Balance on the first mesh point}
\assign{Activity Equation}
\assign{Pressure Drop Equation on the first mesh point}
\assign[10]{\bf{All other Mesh Points}}
\assign{\tt{for k = 1:}$N_p$}
\end{struktogramm}
\end{center}

This is the structogram for the parameter estimation {\tt paramain}
\begin{center}
\begin{struktogramm}(100,50)[Parameter Estimation]
\assign{Set all values needed}
\assign{Display found value for {\tt X}}
\end{struktogramm}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

**Why do they superpose and what can I do to avoid it?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not know this package, but it seems that you have to define the hight of your diagram manually. You gave both diagrams the size `(100,50)` and I adapted that for you. Please read the [manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/struktex/struktex.en.pdf) (PDF, 408 kB), if there is some automatic way.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}    
\usepackage{struktex}

\begin{document}
    This is the structogram for the reactor model, including the deactivation
    \begin{centernss}
        \begin{struktogramm}(100,100)[Model with Deactivation]
            \assign{Get the values from \texttt{global}}
            \assign{get the value for the parameter estimation}
            \assign{Rename \texttt{y} variables to \texttt{T},\texttt{P},$\rho$ and \texttt{a}}
            \assign[10]{\textbf{First Mesh Point}}
            \assign{Calculate $c_{p_1}$ and $Q_{1}$}
            \assign{\tt{for i = 1:}$N_c$}
            \forever
            \assign{Mass Balance on the first mesh point of component \texttt{i}}
            \foreverend
            \assign{Energy Balance on the first mesh point}
            \assign{Activity Equation}
            \assign{Pressure Drop Equation on the first mesh point}
            \assign[10]{\textbf{All other Mesh Points}}
            \assign{\texttt{for k = 1:}$N_p$}
        \end{struktogramm}
    \end{centernss}

    This is the structogram for the parameter estimation {\texttt paramain}
    \begin{centernss}
        \begin{struktogramm}(100,12)[Parameter Estimation]
            \assign{Set all values needed}
            \assign{Display found value for \texttt{X}}
        \end{struktogramm}
    \end{centernss}

    More Text   
\end{document}
```

[image]

Off-topic: Please note that the commands `\tt` and `\bf` are outdated since years. I changed that for you.

Comment: I set `(100,50)` because I saw that it wasn't really affecting the length of the diagram... when it was just one. I guess it also sets at which point the rest of the text starts. Thank you for both suggestions!